# Consistency between predictions

Tags: correlation, predictive-models

In the context of machine learning, consider a scenario where multiple models are trained to make predictions on a particular task, which could be either a regression or classification problem. However, the ground truth data of the target phenomenon is unknown. The objective is to determine whether there exists a metric that can be used to measure the consistency between the predictions of these models. Is there such a metric? Furthermore, it is desirable to investigate whether a method exists for combining these models based on this metric to improve the overall performance of the ensemble.

Comment: You say "consistency" but I think you mean agreement. Concordance is another word that's thrown around in this context.

Comment: In general, you want to explore the topic of Inter-rater reliability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability).